# portfolio/sorting/gallery

Tags: views

I want to use [Views Quicksand](http://drupal.org/project/views_quicksand) for one of my websites. I downloaded the zip folder and put it in

> [yourdrupalroot]/sites/all/modules/views_quicksand/.

Now Views Quicksand shows under the modules tab, but its disabled and says some files are missing. I can't enable it by enabling the checkbox because its not clickable. Please help me in activating the plugin to give the desired effect (http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) to my portfolio page.

Comment: What files are missing? You should add them to make enabling the module possible...

Answer (score 0):

did u forgot to use js plugin with it.

> Download 'jquery.quicksand.js' from 'http://razorjack.net/quicksand/' and put it into
>   [yourdrupalroot]/sites/all/libraries/jquery.quicksand/

Comment: i have put the .js file as well, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Provides a preconfigured view that should always show a working Quicksand animation.
Requires: Views (missing), Views Quicksand (disabled), Libraries (missing) - this is what's written next to the module (which is not active)

Comment: I will be really obliged if u could help me with this ASAP
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As Volker said earlier, please download and enable the missing modules:

- Views (http://drupal.org/project/views)
- Libraries (http://drupal.org/project/libraries)

By doing so you will be able to click and enable the Quicksand module(s).